# How to write the useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have two MobX stores, `AccountStore` and `ExternalAccountStore`.

For simplicity my `AccountStore` looks like this:

```
export default class AccountStore {
    accountRegistry = new Map<string, Account>();

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    get accountsFromMap() {
        return Array.from(this.accountRegistry.values());
    }

    loadAccounts = async () => {
        try {
            const accounts = await agent.Accounts.list(); //this returns an Array and we add the elements below in a map
            runInAction(() => {
                accounts.forEach(account => {
                    this.accountRegistry.set(account.id, account);
                })
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Nothing too fancy, I store some data in a `Map`.
I have another MobX store that is very similar to the one above:

```
export default class ExternalAccountStore {
    externalAccountRegistry = new Map<string, any>();

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    get externalAccountsFromMap(){
        return Array.from(this.externalAccountRegistry.values());
    }

    loadExternalAccounts = async (accounts: any[]) => {
        try {
            console.log("accounts", accounts);
            runInAction(() => {
                accounts.map(async account => {
                    var externalAccount = await agent.ExternalAccount.info('/mytoken', account.apiKey);
                    externalAccount.externalId = account.id;
                    this.externalAccountRegistry.set(externalAccount.externalId, externalAccount);
                })
            })
            console.log("this.externalAccountRegistry", this.externalAccountRegistry);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The `loadExternalAccounts` is expected to receive an array of objects, more precisely, the `accountRegistry` from `AccountStore` via `accountsFromMap`.

I also have a `store.ts` file that allows me to export them in other functions:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import AccountStore from "./accountsStore";
import ExternalAccountStore from "./externalAccountStore";

interface Store {
    accountStore: AccountStore;
    externalAccountStore: ExternalAccountStore;
}

export const store: Store = {
    accountStore: new AccountStore(),
    externalAccountStore: new ExternalAccountStore(),
}

export const StoreContext = createContext(store);

export function useStore() {
    return useContext(StoreContext);
}
```

So far, so good.
Now when try to put it all together and make use of the stores in an observer function:

```
export default observer(function AccountsTable() {
    const { accountStore, externalAccountStore } = useStore();
    const { loadAccounts, accountsFromMap } = accountStore;
    const { loadExternalAccounts, externalAccountsFromMap} = externalAccountStore;

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAccounts().then(() => loadExternalAccounts(accountsFromMap));
    }, [loadAccounts, loadExternalAccounts, accountsFromMap])
    
    return(
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

The result:

[image]

Looks like the `accounts` is initially empty and after that it gets 7 elements. But the externalAccountRegistry is updated first with 0, then 4, then 7 elements? All in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect has dependency on `accountsFromMap` and at the same time it calls a function which updates the value of `accountsFromMap`. So it runs first time, updates the value, then effect runs again because value was updated and so on.